# Not overwrite other columns with similar name by awk in bash

Tags: bash, awk

Sometimes I need to overwrite some values in a file.

For example, my table is:

```
Name;Town;ID
Michal;Vienna;123456
Yasmin;Krakow;12345 
Sarlote;Prague;1234
Karol;Budapest;12348
```

I need to change Sarlote ID from `1234` to `4321`.
I used the following awk command :

```
awk -v h="1234" -v new_value="4321" 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} $1 ~ h $3=new_value}1' OFS=';' file >> file1 && mv file1 file
```

But the output is:

```
Name;Town;ID
Michal;Vienna;4321
Yasmin;Krakow;4321
Sarlote;Prague;4321
Karol;Budapest;4321
```

But I would like to change only `Sarlote` ID.

Comment: Can you show the input file (or a sample) in the exact format (with the `;`, e.g.) you have it along with the exact output you hope to get from that sample? That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: What happens if you change your `$1 ~ h` to `$1 == h` ?

Comment: @Ploutox makes a good point. But, also, wouldn't it be `$3 == h` instead of `$1`?

Comment: I corrected the example. 
If I change $1 == h nothing perform, it is a good way for me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, nothing perform & it is a good way for you ? IMO, the way @jas wrote it should work in your case

Comment: Just to sum up from the comments, the awk script should be: `awk -v h="1234" -v new_value="4321" 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} $3==h {$3=new_value}1' OFS=';'  file >> file1 && mv file1 file` Notice the test condition is on `$3`, not `$1`, the condition is `==` not `~`, and the additional opening bracket is present.

Comment: @JNevill you probably want to add the Sarlote conditon: `awk -v h="1234" -v new_value="4321" 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} $3==h && $1=="Sarlote" {$3=new_value}1' OFS=';'`

Comment: Sneaky! For completeness sake: `awk -v h="1234" -v new_value="4321" 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} $3==h && $1=="Sarlote" {$3=new_value}1' OFS=';' file >> file1 && mv file1 file`  Thanks @fedorqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need is:

```
$ awk -v name="Sarlote" -v newId=4321 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} $1==name{$3=newId} 1' file
Name;Town;ID
Michal;Vienna;123456
Yasmin;Krakow;12345
Sarlote;Prague;4321
Karol;Budapest;12348
```

but if you did need to test the old ID then you'd just add that variable and condition:

```
$ awk -v name="Sarlote" -v oldId=1234 -v newId=4321 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} ($1==name) && ($3==oldId) {$3=newId} 1' file
Name;Town;ID
Michal;Vienna;123456
Yasmin;Krakow;12345
Sarlote;Prague;4321
Karol;Budapest;12348
```